# 100% CPU with Tomcat Pool

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

Below is thread is causing 100% CPU usage randomly, and it only resolves when nodes are restarted, Need help identifying the root cause, My guess is related to some loop which causes CPU SPIKE

```
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE\
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngineResult.<init>(java.base@11.0.18/SSLEngineResult.java:196)\
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeRecord(java.base@11.0.18/SSLEngineImpl.java:164)\
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(java.base@11.0.18/SSLEngineImpl.java:136)\
- eliminated <0x00000000c5c5ebb8> (a sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl)\
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(java.base@11.0.18/SSLEngineImpl.java:116)\
- locked <0x00000000c5c5ebb8> (a sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl)\
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(java.base@11.0.18/SSLEngine.java:482)\
at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.shutdown(SSLSocketChannel.java:381)\
- locked <0x00000000c5c5e868> (a oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel)\
at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.write(SSLSocketChannel.java:242)\
at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:302)\
at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.writeDataToSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:173)\
at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.writeDataToSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:124)\
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.flush(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:727)\
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:733)\
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:413)\
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:485)\
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)\
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:72)\
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:961)\
- eliminated <0x00000000c5c59900> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)\
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:1937)\
- locked <0x00000000c5c59900> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)\
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:1942)\
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)\
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.18/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@11.0.18/Method.java:566)\
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:131)\
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)\
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)\
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)\
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)\
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.commit(Unknown Source)\
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:86)\
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:282)\
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)\
at io.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryHealthCheck.lambda$check$0(SessionFactoryHealthCheck.java:56)\
at io.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryHealthCheck$$Lambda$797/0x0000000840b16440.call(Unknown Source)\
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@11.0.18/FutureTask.java:264)\
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.18/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.18/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedThreadFactory$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedThreadFactory.java:66)\
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.18/Thread.java:834)\
Locked ownable synchronizers:\
- <0x00000000c2c9c570> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)\
```

Comment: Probably yes. Have you tried switching to another connection pool like HikariCP?

Answer (score 5):

Same issue here running Wildfly AS 24.0.1.Final. The problem started with updating from OpenJDK 11.0.17 to 11.0.18 (while running a standard OS update). The stacktraces of the I/O threads causing the CPU load are the same:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeRecord(java.base@11.0.18/SSLEngineImpl.java:271)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(java.base@11.0.18/SSLEngineImpl.java:136)
- eliminated <0x0000000740f3c8b8> (a sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(java.base@11.0.18/SSLEngineImpl.java:116)
- locked <0x0000000740f3c8b8> (a sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(java.base@11.0.18/SSLEngine.java:482)
…
```

The problem occurs when using the 11.0.18 packages of OpenJDK in RHEL 7.9:

```
java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-1.el7_9.x86_64.rpm
java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.18.0.10-1.el7_9.x86_64.rpm
java-11-openjdk-devel-11.0.18.0.10-1.el7_9.x86_64.rpm
```

**Workaround**: Downgrading to OpenJDK 11.0.17. On RedHat Linux, you can proceed this way and avoid updating the Java package automatically:

```
yum downgrade java-11-openjdk-11.0.17.0.8-2.el7_9.x86_64 java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.17.0.8-2.el7_9.x86_64 java-11-openjdk-devel-11.0.17.0.8-2.el7_9.x86_64
yum install yum-plugin-versionlock
yum versionlock java-11-openjdk-*
```

The root cause is still unknown, maybe this is related to https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8273553, but I was not able to confirm this.

**Update**:
In my case, this seems to be a confirmed bug in Undertow: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/UNDERTOW-2239. It is related to JDK 1.8.0_361+, 11.0.18+ or 17.0.6+ (see Oracle support document 2934851.1). So sticking to JDK 11.0.17 (or deactivating SSL) appears to be the only option right now.

Comment: Thank you ver much, we had this problem also when upgrading 11.0.18, and solved it too downgrading to 11.0.17

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact same issue this week with ou server (java 17, spring boot, ...) and with a SQL Server database.

It was resolved by disabling TLS 1.3, but we have yet to investigate further to find the root cause (would be nice to have TLS 1.3 enabled again).

Seems related to this : https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-70169

Comment: Steffen's answer might be useful for you, to downgrade java, and enable TLS again.